# How to add go to top button in the new google sites?

Tags: html, google-sites-2016

I am very confused on how to add a button that shows up when you scroll and then `onclick` takes you to the top of the page again.

Here is an example of such button from the tutorial at `w3school` using html and css:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G6H468JIUSF0

However, if I embed it in google sites with "embed" functionality it will just scroll to the top of the element and not to the top of the page.

I also tried putting html tag and linking it with :

`<a name='top'></a>` at the *top* of the page

`<a href='#top'>Top</a>` at the *bottom*

But this gives an **error** and redirects to :

https://524942313-atari-embeds.googleusercontent.com/embeds/16cb204cf3a9d4d223a0a3fd8b0eec5d/inner-frame-minified.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.y5hhWjOdu80.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNsKzxWFhezE2KkFP7auTmVDBiNEQ%2Fm%3D__features__#top

Answer (score 0):

try this
 at the top of the page

`<a name='top' id="top></a>`

at the bottom

```
<a href='#top'>Top</a>
```

Comment: Did you mean `<a name='top' id="top"></a>`? I tired it right now and still the same error.

Comment: can you use add give me a codepen link so i can check

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share the site. But it seems like a common problem with new google sites. I just cannot find a solution anywhere in the internet.